# Keras: Misunderstanding what Keras does when invoking a Model, providing an Input?

Tags: python, keras, machine-learning-model, data-science-model

In a class named `Generator`, I have defined a model with the below method `define_model`:

```
def define_model(self):
    conv2d = Generator.__last_block()
    output = Activation('tanh')(conv2d)
    model = Model(self.input_layer, output)
    return model
```

In another file, I am writing the entry-point of my Python program, which calls the generator's `define_model` method:

```
generator = Generator()
generator_model = generator.define_model()

input_low_resolution = Input(shape=low_resolution_shape)
generated_high_resolution_images = generator_model(input_low_resolution)
```

As I'm reading a course, I however have a queston about this code: **what does Keras do when it executes the line `generated_high_resolution_images = generator_model(input_low_resolution)`?**

As far I can understand, it doesn't define a model (my model is already defined thanks to `generator.define_model()`!). And since the Keras methods `train`, `fit` or other aren't called, I deduce that this line doesn't train the model.

By the way, it's a really weird line for me, because it passes a parameter to a reference (the reference to the object is `generator_model` and the parameter is `input_low_resolution`). Normally we pass parameters to the reference's methods (constructor and other methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras does a lot of stuff when you call a model. I guess that the most important is that it defines the trainable variables and the graph based on the inputs and outputs. For instance actually making any dense layers, and not just the representations.

For instance, if you did `mod1=generator_model(input_low_resolution)` and `mod2=generator_model(input_low_resolution)`, then if you train `mod1` then `mod2` would not be affected as they have different parameters. So the `.define_model` just makes a "handle" to your model, which when called actually "builds" it.

This functionality is very useful when you want to mix-and-match multiple layer configurations, or working with more complex structures like for instance GANs or ADDA.

I would argue that your implementation is not exactly canonical and actually I'd recommend looking at the [tensorflow.keras.Model example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#class_model). Here they introduce a very nice, canonical way of making your own model.

Furthermore maybe [Keras Model class API](https://keras.io/models/model/) and [Getting started with the Keras functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) can be of help.